# How to move caret to start or middle of a line in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, caret

If you hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key on your keyboard in PyCharm, the caret moves to the end of the line. Is there any key for going to the *start* or *middle* of a line in PyCharm?

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, it asks you to enter a line number, but is the any other to go to the *start* or *end* of the line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From PyCharm's [Keyboard Shortcuts and Mouse Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/keyboard-shortcuts-and-mouse-reference.html):

- <kbd>End</kbd>: Move the caret to the end of line.
- <kbd>Home</kbd>: Move the caret to the beginning of line.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>: Move the caret to the next word.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>: Move the caret to the previous word.

I cannot find any reference to an Action that moves the caret to the middle of a line, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confuse what is end and home in your keyboard than,

End : right arrow

Home : left arrow

Use shortcuts to move fast your cursor use,

Ctrl + End : to move right

Ctrl + Home : to move left